# How can we use .class on primitive types?

Tags: java, class, primitive

When we say

```
Class c = Integer.class;
System.out.println(c);
```

it prints

> `class java.lang.Integer`

which makes sense because `java.lang.Integer` is a class. So we can have a corresponding `Class` object.

But when I do

```
Class c1 = int.class;
System.out.println(c1);
```

it prints `int` which I felt is kind of ambiguous as `.class` returns an object of type `Class` and `int` is not a class (but a primitive type).

What is the motive behind allowing .class operation on primitive types when there is no such class (`primitiveType.class.getName()`) present?

Also if you see `toString(`) method of class `Class`

```
public String toString() {
    return (isInterface() ? "interface " : (isPrimitive() ? "" : "class "))
        + getName();
}
```

As primitive types are not classes or interfaces it simply print the name (`int` for `int`). So why allow creating `Class` objects of a class which is not present?

Comment: I think this is one of antipatterns in java.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is documented in [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html):

> The primitive Java types (boolean, byte, char, short, int, long, float, and double), and the keyword void are also represented as Class objects.

It is particularly useful when you want to call a method that expects primitive arguments via reflection.

Imagine a method:

```
class MyClass {
    void m(int i) {}
}
```

You can access it with:

```
MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethod("m", int.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

Found another application for e.g. `int.class`. Consider to mock the method

```
class MyClass {
    int myMethod(final int arg) {}
}
```

To mock it with Mockito you may use:

```
    when(myClass.myMethod(any(int.class)).thenReturn(1);
```

I was surprised myself that this actually works and it is more clearer than simply

```
    when(myClass.myMethod(any()).thenReturn(1);
```

Answer (score -2):

primitive is not a class. These are some reserved types in Java.

When you say Integer, it's a class in java.lang package such as :

class Integer{
............
}

so for any class you can use .class, Not applicable for primitives. BTW, why do you need this? What is the use?

Comment: Actually you can do `primitive.class` (for example `int.class`). There are use cases for this as @assylias said.